# Loop through an array and print out a template for each iteration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I don't know how to do this and i hope i can get some tips from you.

I get an array with some data from a function. This function is defined in my Controller (HomeController). And the array is built as following:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [message] => xxx
        [name] => yyy
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [message] => xxx
        [name] => yyy
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [message] => xxx
        [name] => yyy
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [message] => xxx
        [name] => yyy
    )

)
```

Now i got this data in my Controller. Next i want to show this data on my view. I want to loop through each data and render it out.

Should i return the array to my view and loop in my view through the array? Or what is the best method for this?

And additionally i got another question. I dont want to just render it out inside the loop. I thought about something like a template. Is it possible to define a template and on every iteration i give the informations from the array to my defined template and then render it out?

The template may look something like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1> $data["name"] </h1>
    <p> $data["message"] </p>
</div>
```

And then the loop maybe like this:

```
foreach(...) {
    // the template is rendered here with the array data
    {{ @template($data) }}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

**Solution:**

(Thanks to James for his input)

```
@foreach ($data as $display)
   @include('templatename', $display)
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there with this:

```
foreach(...) {
    // the template is rendered here with the array data
    {{ @template($data) }}
}
```

Now say we are passing the array through to the view as $data, changing this to the proper [blade syntax](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures):

```
@foreach ($data as $display)
<div class="box">
    <h1>{{ $display['name'] }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $display['message'] }}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

If the array you are referring to is actually returned from an eloquent query then it will be stored in an object rather than an array. In which was you would just change it to this:

```
@foreach ($data as $display)
<div class="box">
    <h1>{{ $display->name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $display->message }}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works fine with your loop, but i also found a way to include a template inside the loop which i think is a good way :) i add it to my question above, you can have a look if you want. have a nice day :)

Comment: yes i know :) but this is just a demo template i made to demonstrate it. Later this template has much more markup and then it's more clear to have it in a template and include this than write all markup inside the loop